# Retrieve values from field_numbers

Tags: mysql, drupal, gravity-forms-plugin

I have been building a form with Gravity Forms on the WordPress CMS.
All the fields are saved inside the MySQL, but right now I need to retrieve these data inside a Drupal CMS.

The connection to the correct database has already been created, but I have no idea how to correctly retrieve the data from the MySQL.

Each person creating a form gets its own ID, in these ID's we have certain field_numbers which has their own value.
For example:
Form ID number 1 has been created and created different field_numbers (that is each question, might be radio box, checkbox or open questions) with different values.

I need to retrieve this form with the corresponding values.
The tables are called:
lead_id (This is the number of the lead).
field_number (these are the numbers of the field created by Gravity Forms).
value (the answer given to a certain kind of field_number).

I hope this isn't to hard to understand. Don't realy know how to explain though.....
I need to retrieve field_number 9 value from all ID's (created forms).
Thanks all for taking a look into this..

I need to retrieve the

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to retrieve the data from Gravity Forms.
Here is a full example of how to retrieve the data from a differtent platform (no WordPress).

`$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'your_username';
$password = 'your_password';
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db('your_databasename');

$sql = 'select lead_id as entryId
,(select value from bjj where field_number=1 and lead_id = entryId) as email
,(select value from bjj where round(field_number,2) = 57.3 and lead_id = entryId) as first_name
,(select value from bjj where round(field_number,2) = 57.6 and lead_id = entryId) as last_name
,(select value from bjj where round(field_number,2) = 58.1 and lead_id = entryId) as address1
,(select value from bjj where round(field_number,2) = 58.2 and lead_id = entryId) as address2
,(select value from bjj where round(field_number,2) = 58.3 and lead_id = entryId) as city
,(select value from bjj where round(field_number,2) = 58.4 and lead_id = entryId) as state
,(select value from bjj where round(field_number,2) = 58.5 and lead_id = entryId) as zip
,(select value from bjj where round(field_number,2) = 58.6 and lead_id = entryId) as country
,(select value from bjj where round(field_number,2) = 63.0 and lead_id = entryId) as phone
,(select value from bjj where round(field_number,2) = 66.0 and lead_id = entryId) as age
from bjj
group by entryId order by entryId desc';
$result = mysql_query ($sql, $conn);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
// output data of each row
    echo "<div class='block-information-leads' style='width: 33%; float: left; border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 10px;'>Voor en achternaam: " . $row["first_name"] . " " . $row["last_name"] . "<br />Type keuken: " . $row["email"]. "<br />Land: " . $row["country"]. "</div>";
}

mysql_close($link);

?>`